# How to translate Text to Binary with Cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa, binary

I'm making a simple Cocoa program that can encode text to binary and decode it back to text. I tried to make this script and I was not even close to accomplishing this. Can anyone help me? This has to include two textboxes and two buttons or whatever is best, Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by “text to binary”? In particular, what do you mean by “binary”? Are you literally trying to print out every bit of every byte of every character as either a 1 or 0, or do you mean something else?

Comment: @PeterHosey I'm trying to print a simple text in every byte in 1 and 0.

Comment: I wouldn't call conversion to binary “encryption”. Encoding at most. Anyway, [Steven Frank's book](http://amzn.com/B005DPIKPE) will help you understand the math that's required.

Comment: @PeterHosey Still does not tell me how to create a program that can convert a text to binary format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to this.

The first is to encode the characters of the string into bytes. You do this by sending the string a `dataUsingEncoding:` message. Which encoding you choose will determine which bytes it gives you for each character. Start with `NSUTF8StringEncoding`, and then experiment with other encodings, such as `NSUnicodeStringEncoding`, once you get it working.

The second part is to convert every bit of every byte into either a `'0'` character or a `'1'` character, so that, for example, the letter A, encoded in UTF-8 to a single byte, will be represented as `01000001`.

So, converting characters to bytes, and converting bytes to characters representing bits. These two are *completely separate* tasks; the second part should work correctly for any stream of bytes, including any valid stream of encoded characters, any *invalid* stream of encoded characters, and indeed anything that isn't text at all.

The first part is easy enough:

```
- (NSString *) stringOfBitsFromEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
    ofString:(NSString *)inputString
{
    //Encode the characters to bytes using the UTF-8 encoding. The bytes are contained in an NSData object, which we receive.
    NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //I did say these were two separate jobs.
    return [self stringOfBitsFromData:data];
}
```

For the second part, you'll need to loop through the `bytes` of the data. A C `for` loop will do the job there, and that will look like this:

```
//This is the method we're using above. I'll leave out the method signature and let you fill that in.
- …
{
    //Find out how many bytes the data object contains.
    NSUInteger length = [data length];
    //Get the pointer to those bytes. “const” here means that we promise not to change the values of any of the bytes. (The compiler may give a warning if we don't include this, since we're not allowed to change these bytes anyway.)
    const char *bytes = [data bytes];

    //We'll store the output here. There are 8 bits per byte, and we'll be putting in one character per bit, so we'll tell NSMutableString that it should make room for (the number of bytes times 8) characters.
    NSMutableString *outputString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:length * 8];

    //The loop. We start by initializing i to 0, then increment it (add 1 to it) after each pass. We keep looping as long as i < length; when i >= length, the loop ends.
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        char thisByte = bytes[i];

        for (NSUInteger bitNum = 0; bitNum < 8; ++bitNum) {
            //Call a function, which I'll show the definition of in a moment, that will get the value of a bit at a given index within a given character.
            bool bit = getBitAtIndex(thisByte, bitNum);

            //If this bit is a 1, append a '1' character; if it is a 0, append a '0' character.
            [outputString appendFormat: @"%c", bit ? '1' : '0'];
        }
    }

    return outputString;
}
```

#### Bits 101 (or, 1100101)

Bits are literally just digits in base 2. Humans in the Western world usually write out numbers in base 10, but a number is a number no matter what base it's written in, and every character, and every byte, and indeed every bit, is just a number.

Digits—including bits—are counted up from the lowest place, according to the exponent to which the base is raised to find the magnitude of that place. We want bits, so that base is 2, so our place values are:

- 2^0 = 1: The ones place (the lowest bit)
- 2^1 = 2: The twos place (the next higher bit)
- 2^2 = 4: The fours place
- 2^3 = 8: The eights place

And so on, up to 2^7. (Note that the highest exponent is exactly one lower than the number of digits we're after; in this case, 7 vs. 8.)

If that all reminds you of reading about “the ones place”, “the tens place”, “the hundreds place”, etc. when you were a kid, it should: it's the exact same principle.

So a byte such as 65, which (in UTF-8) completely represents the character 'A', is the sum of:

```
  2^7 × 0 = 0
+ 2^6 × 0 = 64
+ 2^5 × 1 = 0
+ 2^4 × 0 = 0
+ 2^3 × 0 = 0
+ 2^2 × 0 = 0
+ 2^1 × 0 = 0
+ 2^0 × 1 = 1
= 0 + 64 +0+0+0+0+0 + 1
= 64 + 1
= 65
```

Back when you learned base 10 numbers as a kid, you probably noticed that ten is “10”, one hundred is “100”, etc. This is true in base 2 as well: as 10^x is “1” followed by x “0”s in base 10, so is 2^x “1” followed by “x” 0s in base 2. So, for example, sixty-four in base 2 is “1000000” (count the zeroes and compare to the table above).

We are going to use these exact-power-of-two numbers to *test* each bit in each input byte.

#### Finding the bit

C has a pair of “shift” operators that will insert zeroes or remove digits at the low end of a number. The former is called “shift left”, and is written as `<<`, and you can guess the opposite.

We want shift left. We want to shift 1 left by the number of the bit we're after. That is exactly equivalent to raising 2 (our base) to the power of that number; for example, `1 << 6` = 2^6 = “1000000”.

#### Testing the bit

C has an operator for bit testing, too; it's `&`, the bitwise AND operator. (Do not confuse this with `&&`, which is the *logical* AND operator. `&&` is for using whole true/false values in making decisions; `&` is one of your tools for working with bits within values.)

Strictly speaking, `&` does not test single bits; it goes through the bits of both input values, and returns a new value whose bits are the bitwise AND of each input pair. So, for example,

```
  01100101
& 00101011
----------
  00100001
```

Each bit in the output is 1 if and only if *both* of the corresponding input bits were also 1.

#### Putting these two things together

We're going to use the shift left operator to give us a number where one bit, the nth bit, *is* set—i.e., 2^n—and then use the bitwise AND operator to test whether the same bit is also set in our input byte.

```
//This is a C function that takes a char and an int, promising not to change either one, and returns a bool.
bool getBitAtIndex(const char byte, const int bitNum)
//It could also be a method, which would look like this:
//- (bool) bitAtIndex:(const int)bitNum inByte:(const char)byte
//but you would have to change the code above. (Feel free to try it both ways.)
{
    //Find 2^bitNum, which will be a number with exactly 1 bit set. For example, when bitNum is 6, this number is “1000000”—a single 1 followed by six 0s—in binary.
    const int powerOfTwo = 1 << bitNum;

    //Test whether the same bit is also set in the input byte.
    bool bitIsSet = byte & powerOfTwo;

    return bitIsSet;
}
```

#### A bit of magic I should acknowledge

The bitwise AND operator does *not* evaluate to a single bit—it does not evaluate to only 1 or 0. Remember the above example, in which the `&` operator returned 33.

The `bool` type is a bit magic: Any time you convert any value to `bool`, it automatically becomes either 1 or 0. Anything that is not 0 becomes 1; anything that is `0` becomes `0`.

The Objective-C `BOOL` type *does not do this*, which is why I used `bool` in the code above. You are free to use whichever you prefer, except that you generally should use `BOOL` whenever you deal with anything that expects a `BOOL`, particularly when overriding methods in subclasses or implementing protocols. You can convert back and forth freely, though not losslessly (since `bool` will change non-zero values as described above).

#### Oh yeah, you said something about text boxes too

When the user clicks on your button, get the `stringValue` of your input field, call `stringOfBitsFromEncoding:ofString:` using a reasonable encoding (such as UTF-8) and that string, and set the resulting string as the new `stringValue` of your output field.

Extra credit: Add a pop-up button with which the user can choose an encoding.

Extra extra credit: Populate the pop-up button with all of the available encodings, without hard-coding or hard-nibbing a list.